# How can I make a reliable piston door?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-legacy-console

My friend has a "empires" world and my castle is located on the water. I need a piston door that a boat can fit through with out breaking. Currently, I use a 2x2 piston door. (keep in mind the boat has two blocks of clearance) The door is too small to have a boat safely sail through. Any ideas on how to make a reliable door? (not mentioned before, boats are the #1 thing to use in travel and trade, and there are few safe ways to put down a secure mine cart track) Extra: boats have a mind of their own at points, turning the exact wrong way you want them to.

Comment: To work with a boat without breaking it is a challenge in itself...

Comment: @Unionhawk It is a challenge! My friend accually threatened to raid my city if I dont fix the door!

Answer (score 2):

One easy(ish) solution is to use a sand door. You can make them as wide as you would like, and about 3 high.

Here's one design that should work with the XBOX edition:

If you want to do some searching, what you want is a tileable triple piston extender for Minecraft 1.0.1. Or, if you only need it to be 2 high, then you only need a double piston extender, which is quite an easy design.

Comment: I need a piston door that people (my friends that live in my city) CANT break with their fist. I need a door that uses pistons and stone brick.

Comment: Easyish? Man I suck...

Comment: I will admit, I've not done redstone on XBOX, so, I can't really say how easy exactly it would be.

As for your break with fists problem... I'm going to think about that one. And search long for a larger than 2x2 door for 1.0.1. Maybe a full blown portcullis (castle gate) would work? It would still be semi-easily broken, but not quite as easily as sand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a photo of a very compact 3x3 piston door[image: 3x3 piston door photo]

P.S.:be sure to place obsidian on the bottom of the pistons. Also set all repeaters to 4 ticks

Comment: Not really anti-fist. Slime blocks break easily